# Optimization: Create a list of clusters in the most optimized way

Tags: r

I have a data frame that consists of pairs, it looks like this:

```
Col_1  Col_2

A      B 
B      G
A      C
D      F
E      F
```

Now, from this dataframe of pairs, I want to create a list as output that looks like this:

```
output[[1]]
> A B G C

output[[2]]
> D F E
```

The order of the output does not matter, (both of all the elements and within an element)

I have written some lengthy code, which looks inefficient to me. (I'm happy to share it if anyone wants to see it) Is there any efficient way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way involves the `igraph` library:

```
clusters <- clusters(graph.data.frame(df, directed = FALSE))$membership
split(names(clusters), clusters)

$`1`
[1] "A" "B" "G" "C"

$`2`
[1] "D" "E" "F"
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much!!! I have a data frame of over a million reccords and this completes it in less than 3 seconds ... :o